# Open URLs without prefix 'http://' from command line

Tags: command-line

I can open a URL from command as:

```
open http://www.google.com
```

If I tried:

```
open www.google.com
The file ~/www.google.com does not exist.
Perhaps you meant 'http://www.google.com'?
```

Nevertheless, it works on Windows like:

```
start www.google.com
```

It's not convenient to add 'http://' every time.
How to solve the problem?

Comment: A URL must begin with a protocol ie the bit before the : so what you have is not a URL. How does the system know to add http it could be mail: ftp: https: etc So the question is where do you get the partial information from and how do you make that app supply the correct information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Mark said](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317787/open-urls-without-prefix-http-from-command-line/317797#comment404424_317787),

> A URL must begin with a protocol ie the bit before the : so what you have is not a URL.

You'll need to create your own wrapper for the open command. For example, you can use this function to prepend `http`:

```
function openweb() { open http://$1 }
```

Run with `openweb google.com` or `openweb www.google.com`.

Place this in a profile file such as `~/.bash_profile` to be available in all interactive shells.